# Why does item with navigation link in list become blue?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I embedded my item in list(row) in navigation link

And my item became blue [click](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT3Pv.png)

here is my code:

ToysRow.swift

```
struct ToyRow: View {
    var category: String
    var toys:[Toy]

    var body: some View {

        Group {
            VStack{

                VStack(alignment: .leading){
                    Text(category).padding().font(.largeTitle)
                    ScrollView(.horizontal, showsIndicators: false){
                        HStack(alignment: .top){
                            ForEach(self.toys){
                                toy1 in
                                NavigationLink(destination: ToyDetail(toy: toy1)) {
                                    ToyItem(toy: toy1)
                                }.padding()

                            }
                        }
                    }

                }
            }
        }

    }
}
```

so creating NavigationView doesn't help –– it becomes gray

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because of the default `accentColor` ('aka' `tintColor`)

## With Code:

add this modifier to your `Image`:

```
.renderingMode(.original)
```

## Without Code:

1. Go to `Assets.xcassets` from the project navigator and **select your image** there.
2. From the right panel, **Attributes Inspector**
3. Select `Original Image` for **Render As**

[image: Inspector]

**Remember** you should always do this for all images that you don't want to apply any color on them.

### For text and Icons:

use `.accentColor()` modifier

Comment: And what should I do with text? Just manually change the color?

Comment: use `.accentColor()` as I mentioned in the beginning of the answer. I have added to the end of the answer again ;)

Answer (score -1):

**For Text use**

```
 .foregroundColor( Color(UIColor.label))
```